# under the php while loop I have an orderd list it return the list with the same number of the first item

Tags: php, html

under the while loop I have an ordered list it return the list with the same number of the first item

this is my php code

```
<?php
  $all_tutorials = " select * from tutorials where active = 1";
  $result = $db -> query ($all_tutorials) or die ($db->error);
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_object()) {
    ?>

  <ol>
  <li><?php echo $row->tutorial_title ?></li>
  </ol>

  <?php 
        }
    }
  ?>
```

it returns the items some thing like this

1 blah blah blah blah blah blah ,
1 blah blah blah blah blah blah ,
1 blah blah blah blah blah blah ,

which it should be something like this

1. blah blah blah blah blah blah
2. blah blah blah blah blah blah
3. blah blah blah blah blah blah

please someone tell me how to do this under the loop

Thanks

Comment: What? Please make your question more clear.

Comment: What's the difference between 1 & 2???

Comment: You show identical lists? Can you explain what exactly you need?

Comment: don't you are kidding and asking all stupid questions??

Comment: I believe all three times you are getting output as `1. blah blah blah blah blah blah` `1.blah blah blah blah blah blah` & `1. blah blah blah blah blah blah` and NOT 1,2,3

Comment: see Aaron W. answer... it answer your query...

Comment: sorry Aaron W. got my point, it's my fault, I mean it return 1. blah blah blah blah blah
1. blah blah blah blah blah 1. blah blah blah blah blah, you see the same number appear in all items and it should be returned 1,2,3 like this it Fixed by taking off the <ol> out of the loop but are there is any other why for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `<ol>` tags on the outside of the `while`.

```
<?php
$all_tutorials = " select * from tutorials where active = 1";
$result = $db -> query ($all_tutorials) or die ($db->error);
if ($result) {
    ?>
    <ol>
    <?php
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_object()) {
    ?>

    <li><?php echo $row->tutorial_title; ?></li>

    <?php 
    }
    ?>
    </ol>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: yes Thanks Aaron W. it's fixed but are there any other why to do that just for knowledge

Comment: There's plenty of different ways to do it, but that's your most basic. What other way would you want to do it?